# Can't create a folder in "main" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, directory

I'm trying to create a folder in "main" in Android Studio using the steps shown in the attachment.

What I'm trying to achieve eventually is to have a BLUE directory (A folder)under main, so I can add packages to it. I'm following the steps to achieve that but I always end up with a brown directory(A logical group not an actual folder).

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if Android Studio is just crushing my hopes and dreams lol.

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add folders or packages in java directory not in main

`Create new directory` under **main** < **java**

Comment: No option for "Directory" for in Java folder, the options are Java class, Android resource file, Android resource directory, File, Package.

Comment: Package should be thing.. Package means a directory in the java folder.

Comment: Okay I guess the video I'm watching is a bit old. But yeah eventually skipping that "folder" step and create package directly under Java would solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Project` to `Android` and add directory in `java`. If you want to create a folder like this, create outside Android Studio.

Comment: I don't have a "Directory" option there. In "Android" view, Right Click "Java" folder, "New", the options are Java class, Android resource file, Android resource directory, File, Package